# How to add privacy for android studio apk?

Tags: android-studio

Is there a permission I should add to android manifest to block bluetooth transfer ?? the user shouldn't be able to send the application to anyone via bluetooth ... Is there any way ? thank you so much !

Comment: If the user can't send the application (APK file I assume) via Bluetooth, he can still transfer via other means, like Wi-Fi. What's the point?

Comment: I know this! But is there any way to block the bluetooth ??